# How to get data from a website that can only be viewed in chrome

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate a way to pull data from a website but that website only allows me to view in chrome, firefox, safari, or opera.

I added the url into excel to power query but I'm not able to get the data I'm looking for as I get this error message below.

Any suggestions or recommendations are highly appreciated.

[web address wont work with ie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SohcX.png)

Comment: Use selenium basic. Have you got any code to share? An URL /HTML and the desired data you want? At present this is off topic as is really asking for recommendations rather than specific programming problem. [Ask]

Comment: Use xml http to get the data.

Comment: ^^ https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

Comment: Have you tried it on a newer IE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selenium Basic](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/). It will require the end user to have that framework installed, but works like a charm when Internet Explorer and MSXML aren't an option (if MSXML works, that would be preferable as it is the fastest way to retrieve data - you can find [examples and explanations here](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) as recommended by [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr)).

Note: you'll also have to update the driver that originally comes with the framework installation (you can get the [latest driver for chrome here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and the file to be replaced can be found in the root folder of Selenium Basic's installation `C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic`).

You'll have to select the appropriate reference within the VBA IDE: "Selenium Type Driver" and then the code goes like this:

```
Public Sub SeleniumImplementation()
    Dim driver As New Selenium.WebDriver ' in older versions was SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

    'Late binding would be:
    'Dim driver As Object
    'Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.WebDriver")

    driver.start "chrome", "http://news.yahoo.com"
    driver.open "/politics"
    driver.stop
End Sub
```

You should be able to get the rest of the syntax from the autocomplete and object browser and you can take a look at [more code examples here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/selenium-vba/).

If Chrome is too slow, you can try PhantomJS which comes with Selenium's installation.

(Note: the code is untested.)

Comment: Worth mentioning that chromedriver must be on the environmental path; and that the path section (for the driver) should be up to, but not including, the .exe (i.e. to the containing folder level), I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already tried on internet explorer and it didn't work I would suggest trying the following function

```
dim ie as internetexplorermedium
```

It helps if you have securities on internet explorer. It will make your life much easier if you can use that instead.